# asp:Button css style issue, want to mimick exact css of my a.button class

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm having some difficulties applying styles to an asp:button. I've read a few posts on here and can't seem to apply what people are saying to my situation.

I have the following css setup for my href tags.

```
a.button { padding:6px;background:#4A6491;color:#FFF; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;margin:10px 2px;text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold;border:2px solid transparent; }
a.button:hover { border:2px solid #fff; }
```

however I have an asp:button that is already wired up to do some login jazz that I would like to apply the exact same style but can't seem to get my styles to work.

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
a.button, input[type=submit] { padding:6px;background:#4A6491;color:#FFF; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;margin:10px 2px;text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold;border:2px solid transparent; }
a.button:hover, input[type=submit]:hover { border:2px solid #fff; }
```

If wish to make the link and button behave in a similar fashion you may also want to add the `cursor:pointer;` style to the first definition.

```
a.button, input[type=submit] { cursor:pointer; .... }
```

Comment: Right on the money, did exactly what i wanted it to! thank you!